# Mongoose increment value not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to increment a value and assign it back to the key.

```
const TopicSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    count: Number
});
```

`topic.count += 2`

Instead of 4, `22` returned. If I do it a couple of times, it is always appending 2 to the end like `2222`.

What's wrong?

Comment: It is happening because you are adding two string... check the `typeof` of number 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you are concatenating strings instead of adding numbers. Try wrapping `topic.count` in `Number( )`

Answer (score 1):

If you'are trying to update the document you better use `$inc` operator provided by `mongodb`. Read more about it [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/).

By the way, this is how you can get it done in a single query

```
db.topic.update(
{ }, //your filter here
{ $inc: { count: 2} }
 )
```